# Lost address book contacts in upgrade to Yosemite

Tags: macos, contacts

I upgraded from the Mavericks to Yosemite on a Macbook Pro. All the contacts in the address book which is now Contacts in Yosemite are gone and when I try to restore it from the back up it gives a message that all the contacts will be replaced which is ok in this case. However when I close the address book after the import and re open it the address have disappeared. After a few attempts it now gives the same message but now the contacts don't even show in the address book anymore. Is there a solution for this?

Thanks 
Usman

Comment: The same thing is happening to me. I see many errors in Console, labeled "Contacts". Do you see that?

Comment: Haven't seen that in the Console.